# Twitter API and writing acceptance tests in python

Tags: python, api, unit-testing, integration-testing

If I am using python, how would I write Acceptance Tests for the Twitter API? Do I download and install Tweepy and begin there? I hope this isn't to vague a question. What exactly does it mean to write Acceptance Tests for an API?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test a code, which is trying to access Twitter API and want to do so in test suite, you probably need to make it "Twitter" independent and mockup Twitter behaviour, so that you can test even without having access to Internet.

There are multiple packages, allowing to do that:

- [`responses`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/responses/0.2.0) in case, your code is based on using `requests`
- [`HTTPPretty`](https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/HTTPretty), which shall be able serving anything, what uses sockets.

Comment: Thanks man! Twitter is sending me a exercise for a job interview all they said was I have to test an api using java python or c++

Comment: @MikeMcmahon In that case, one advice: Every good SW solution start with Requirement Engineering phase - finding out, asking for, or deciding for your own clear definition of what is really required to deliver. Without clear definition, you have minimal chance to deliver working solution.